# generating HTML from XSL-FO using Java

Tags: java, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have some PDF files generated based on some XSL-FO documents and I now need this content in HTML too. I am using FOP for creating the PDF files but this does not support HTML as an output format.

My question is this: Is there a Java library of some sort that can create HTML files based on XSL-FO documents, or can I do this with throwing XSLT at it. Can I somehow extend FOP to create me this type of output?

If XSLT is the only way to go, is there one already created? (I imagine I am not the first dude wanting this)

Thank you all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the  [**Render-X** provided **FO2HTML** stylesheet](http://services.renderx.com/Content/tools/fo2html.html) to convert the **XSL-FO** into **XHTML** output. It converts `<block>` elements into `<div>`, `<inline>` into `<span>`, etc.

I have used it, and it works great.